# Set position of an actor in LibGDX that have an action

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I have a table of actors that are doing different actions (moving, jumping etc) and I want to move all of them to the left as the player moves so I tried

```
setPosition(getX() - 1, getY());
```

But it seems that this only moves the actors that are currently not busy doing MoveTo actions? I have enemies running from one side of the screen to the other with MoveTo actions, I want them to continue doing that but also move to the left at the correct speed.

I tried adding an additional action onto them

```
MoveByAction move = new MoveByAction();
move.setAmount(1, 0);
addAction(Actions.forever(move));
```

But they still seem to continue with their preset MoveTo action.

Comment: i think you should really implement a camera on your project instead moving everything when the player goes to left.. http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/11/06/LibGDX-Tutorial-7-Camera-basics.aspx

Comment: Yes, way easier to move the camera and/or player. What you pointed out is a shortcoming of the Actions in Libgdx. I think you'd have to do a search of each Actor's actions for move actions, get the final position, remove the move action, and give it a new move action where the final position is offset by the amount you want.

Comment: Have you added your enemy actors to a Group object? So that you can move the parent object and get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't do it like that. I had to move actors with setPosition(getX() + 1, getY()); instead of using an action if I wanted to move them seperately.

Also had to use a camera to "move" the entire scene at once.